# Function that inserts an element into a vector and displaces all other elements over, truncating the final element

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function InsertVector that inserts an element (**elem**) into a vector in a position **pos** and then displaces all other values to the right, truncating the last value of the vector and returning its value;  **sz** is the size of the vector.

Here is the code:

```
//InsertVector function:

int InsertVector (vector <int> V, int sz, int pos, int elem) {


    int tmp=V.at(sz-1);

    V.insert(V.begin()+pos-1, elem);

    for(int i(pos);i<=sz-2;i=i+1) {

        int tmp2(V.at(i));
        V.at(i)=V.at(i-1);
        V.at(i+1)=tmp2;

    }

    return tmp;
```

And here is my attempt to test the function on the main:

```
int main() {

    vector<int>V;
    V.push_back(2);
    V.push_back(3);
    V.push_back(4);

    int sz(0);
    sz=V.size();

    int pos(0);
    int elem(0);
    cout<<"enter the position desired to modify here"<<endl;
    cin>>pos;
    cout<<"enter value to replace with here"<<endl;
    cin>>elem;

    InsertVector(V, sz, pos, elem);
    PrintVector(V, sz);


}
```

**note**: PrintVector is another function I created that prints the elements of the vector and that has the following form:

```
void PrintVector(const vector <int> v1, int sz) {

    for (int i(0);i<sz;i++) {

        cout<<"V["<<i<<"] ="<<v1[i]<<endl;

    }

}
```

When I compile Xcode gives an error (lldb).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you know that you want the the number of entries in a vector, you shouldn't introduce extraneous variables like `sz`.  Doing such things increases the chances that you pass an incorrect value.  Use the `vector::size()` method instead.

Comment: Also, what if the vector is empty?

Comment: Ah ok thank you! I will try to write it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to displace all the values to right. `V.insert()` will do  that itself. You can just remove the last element to truncate the list. To remove the last element, use `v.pop_back()`